# jQuery-like animation support in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my codes using "jquery":

```
$("#myElement").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("fast", ->
    $('a')[0].click()
)
```

I fadeIn an element first, then fadeOut it, when fadeOut is completed, I triggered the click event of `<a>`..

I tried to add this snippet in a function (`$scope.myFadeFunc`) under angular context, when I execute `$scope.myFadeFunc`, the browser throws an error:

> Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression:myFadeFunc

However, the fadeIn/fadeOut effect works pretty well.. It seems that this is just **warning** instead of **error**. I was wondering what is the recommended way to do this animation in pure AngularJS style..

Does anyone have ideas about how to do this in AngularJS without jQuery?

Comment: Can you show the code for your function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the angular documentation for [animation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)

With that you could probably string together some complex [css key frame animation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/). Just figure out how long the animation should be and and adjust the keyframe percentages accordingly. As for `$('a')[0].click()` at the end, you'll have to handle that separately

Answer (score 0):

Best way to animate something in Angular is to use the [ngAnimate directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) plus [these awesome css animations](http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/)!

Those css animations are kinda old (from 2013), but works without issues with latest version of Angular.